# Cloud Scheduler not getting created automatically with firebase deploy command

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli, google-cloud-scheduler

When I deploy the firebase functions using `firebase deploy` the cron function says it is deployed successfully and the related Cloud Scheduler has been created. It creates the firebase cron entry in the firebase functions console but the Cloud Schedulers are getting created automatically. Moreover, when I try to create those schedulers manually, it gives the error:

```
Creating job "firebase-schedule-couponCronForExpiredCoupons-us-central1" failed: Unknown error
```

Also, I don't see any schedulers in this list: https://console.cloud.google.com/cloudscheduler

Here is my code:

```
const couponCronForExpiredCoupons = functions.region("asia-east2").pubsub.schedule("* * * * *").timeZone("Asia/Kolkata").onRun(async () => {
    console.log("----------couponCronForExpiredCoupons")
    return null
})
```

I am following this documentation https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions

Comment: If function deployment isn't working the way you expect, contact Firebase support directly for assistance.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: I have already contacted them. Thanks.